# Firebase Unity Initialization not working

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am following the firebase tutorials but cannnot get the first step working.
It says to initialize firebase like this:

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            // Set a flag here indiciating that Firebase is ready to use by your
            // application.
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        }
    });
```

But as soon as it hits the first line of code, it jumps over the entire thing and does not execute.

I've add the google-services.json. I have the latest firebaseunity.package installed.

Any ideas??

Comment: Those lines of code check (and optionally update) the version of Google Play services, so it should be ok that they are ignored. Are you able to use any Firebase related method afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync() is an async operation. That means it runs on a different thread parallel to your other executing code. This is done this way that your game does not freeze while the Firebase SDK is figuring things out in the background like loading the google-services.json.

Once Firebase is done it will call the code which is inside the {} following "task =>" this is a callback which is called by Firebase. You could also write it like this:

```
private void Awake() {
   Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(CalledAfterSomeTime);
}


private void CalledAfterSomeTime(Task<DependencyStatus> task) {
  var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
  if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
    // Set a flag here indiciating that Firebase is ready to use by your
    // application.
  }
  else
  {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
    // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
  }
}
```

Comment: While the rest seems correct, it should be mentioned that async does not necessarily imply that it's running on a different thread, and in most cases it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by forcing your `ContinueWith` sentence to be done in the Unity's main thread. For this, just use `ContinueWithOnMainThread` (available in the `namespace:Firebase.Extensions`) instead of `ContinueWith`.

Example:

```
void Start()
{
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        //...
    });
}
```

Comment: `FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread` this goes never-ending. Why? and `ContinueWith(task)` doesn't get work. Any Solutions?